# ¿Cómo calcular valores de una columna en función de valores de otra?

Tags: r

El índice de masa corporal (IMC) es una medida biométrica de la relación entre la talla y el peso de un individuo. Los datos del IMC se recopilaron en el siguiente vector:

```
imc <- c(18, 19, 24, 25, 30, 35, 30, 20, 18, 15)
```

El criterio de los expertos para clasificar los grupos es el siguiente:

```
bajo (<18,55); Normal (18.55-25) y sobrepeso (> 30)
```

Con esta información crea un vector de factores llamado `imcRangos` de `imc` que muestra los valores, bajo, normal y sobrepeso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te comento que te falta una categoría "Normal Superior", de todas formas se me ocurre una manera simple de resolver tu pregunta, tal vez no la mejor:

```
imc_tipo <- function(val) {
  if (val < 18.55) {
    return("Bajo")
  }
  if (val >= 18.55 & val < 25) {
    return("Normal")
  }  
  if (val >= 25 & val < 30) {
    return("Superior Normal")
  }
  if (val >= 30) {
    return("Sobrepeso")
  }
}

imc <- c(18, 19, 24, 25, 30, 35, 30, 20, 18, 15)
cbind(imc,sapply(imc,imc_tipo))
```

Answer (score 1):

** Actualizada en función de los comentarios:

El ejemplo:

```
imc <- data.frame(imc = c(18, 19, 24, 25, 30, 35, 30, 20, 18, 15))
```

Con `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

imc %>% 
  mutate(cat = cut(imc, 
                   breaks = c(-Inf, 18.55, 25, 30, Inf), 
                   labels = c("bajo", "normal", "normal superior", "sobrepeso")))
```

---

Anterior:

```
imc %>% 
  mutate(cat = ifelse(
    imc < 18.55, "bajo", ifelse(
      imc < 25, "normal", ifelse(
        imc < 30, "superior normal", "sobrepeso"))))

   imc             cat
1   18            bajo
2   19          normal
3   24          normal
4   25 superior normal
5   30       sobrepeso
6   35       sobrepeso
7   30       sobrepeso
8   20          normal
9   18            bajo
10  15            bajo
```

Comment: Gracias chicos, otra duda, con la función "cut" seria posible resolver este problema?

Comment: Sería mejor! Ahí lo agrego!